# Linear Models, Statistics

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

[image]

For part (a), do I need to calculate the MLE of the betas?

For the second part, I'm not really sure how to approach this question.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Not necessarily, because you can view this model as 
   $$
   Y=\mu + \epsilon,
   $$
   thus $Y_i \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, hence $\hat{\mu}_n =  \bar{Y}_n$, where $\bar{Y}_n \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2/n)$.

Clearly, if you are interested in the MLE for each of the coefficients, you will have to find the MLE using $Y_i \sim N(\beta_0 + \beta_1x_i+ \beta_2z_i, \sigma^2)$, i.e., take derivatives w.r.t all the three parameters.

2. I would try $Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 (x_{t_i} - \bar{x}_{t_n})+\epsilon_i$, where $x_{t_i} = e^{-t_i}$ and $\epsilon_i \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$.